# How to convert a String to an Integer in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to `insert`/`update` data into a MySQL table by using a `csv`-like data :

```
function execInsertOrUpdateCompteRendu($compterendu)  // here $compterendu is something like this : -1;2012/03/06 09h 50mn;3;1; 
{
        $resultat = explode("\n",$compterendu);
        $connec = mysql_connect("192.168.1.123:3306","root", "mysqlroot");
        mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connec);
        mysql_select_db("finance",$connec);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($resultat) ; $i++)
        {
            $valeur=explode(";",$resultat[$i]);
            if ($valeur[0] > 0)
            {
                $requete = mysql_query("UPDATE compte_rendu SET  
                cr_date    = '".convertFromDateHM($valeur[1])."',
                cr_lieu    = '".$valeur[2]."',
                cred_id    = '".$valeur[3]."',
                cr_resultat = '".$valeur[5]."',
                cr_comment = '".$valeur[6]."',
                adc_id = '".$valeur[7]."' 
                WHERE cr_id = '".$valeur[0]."'");
            }
            else
            {
                $requete = mysql_query("INSERT INTO compte_rendu SET 
                                        cred_id = '".$valeur[3]."',
                                        cr_date = '".convertFromDateHM($valeur[1])."',
                                        cr_lieu = '".$valeur[2]."',
                                        cr_resultat = '".$valeur[5]."',
                                        cr_comment = '".$valeur[6]."',
                                        adc_id = '".$valeur[7]."'");
            }
        }
        return $resultat[0];
}
```

This `PHP` code is a `web-service` which I call from a `J2ME` client. The problem is that new data are not inserted in the table when I run the J2ME application ! I debugged the java program and there are no errors there. So what is wrong in my `PHP` code ?

Comment: What does the final query look like? Have you checked `mysql_error` for errors?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your servers error log? If so please post them in your question

Comment: You are wrapping everything you insert/update with quotation marks in your query (not required). I'm going to assume you are talking about the IDs in regards to string->integer. So in some sections you should have `adc_id = ".$valeur[7]."` instead of `adc_id = '".$valeur[7]."'`. However, for starters you should be using prepared statements

Comment: Thanks all : I tested if there is an error in the PHP side and in the java program I displayed it by using the response of the webservice and I got : `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`finance`.`compte_rendu`, CONSTRAINT `fk_association_50` FOREIGN KEY (`adc_id`) REFERENCES `adc` (`adc_id`)).` So there is a foreign key issue. Thanks all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could try escaping all the text you're entering into your database with `mysql_real_escape_string` - otherwise you're leaving potential for issues to arise. e.g.

```
//cr_lieu    = '".mysql_real_escape_string($valeur[2])."',
```

Also - to convert a string to integer?

```
$int = (int)$string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQLi prepared statements. You can then bind parameters as integers, doubles, strings or blobs. Have a read of the [Mysqli Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and in regards to binding the [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) section.

In regards to your queries: You shouldn't have to wrap the integer values in quotes